# non trivial rotation invariant subspaces of $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb C^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

i have two questions. First one is: am i correct in thinking that a line vector subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ is rotation invariant if $\theta = \pi$ or $2\pi$?   Second, i am told that there is a non trivial rotation invariant subspace of $\Bbb C^2$ for $\theta = \pi/2$ but i am having trouble visualizing it (considering a rectangle or circle is not a space how could this happen?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is rotation invariant if the angle is 2pi. Of course with the angle being pi, the original vector and its image become a linear dependent set. No vector is mapped onto itself except for an angle being 0. What does that mean for the eigenvalues of the 2 dimensional rotation matrix? Something to think about...

Comment: The first one: yes. The second one: how do you define a rotation in $\mathbb{C}^n$ (for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, or just for $n = 2$, if it's easier for you)?

Comment: Honestly, the second part of your question I do not know, hopefully somebody else may have a clue.....

Comment: Vedran that just gave me food for thought...i believed rotation on C^2 to be defined(and visualized) the same way as in R^2. Am i mistaken in this?...A thought i had was to pick the subspace [x iy] | x,y are in R. But even then, when the pi/2 rotation matrix rotates it we end up with [iy -x] which doesn't belong to that space...

Comment: what if we used the isomorphism  between \mathbb{R}^{2} and \mathbb{C} and pick the vector [x y] in where both x,y belong to the reals. But, in our complex Euclidean space, that vector belongs to the x (or y) axis. Then any rotation we apply outputs a vector [m n] where m,n belong to the reals, hence [m n] may be attributed to the same x (or y) axis, and this space is invariant.
Does this make sense? Thanks